# How do I send a base64 image to Microsoft-ocr api?

Tags: image, api, binary, base64, microsoft-ocr

I'm trying to use Microsoft Azure OCR API service to extract some text from an image.

The image I have for sending to the API service has a "data:image/png; base64, " structure and therefore I can't send it with content-type "application/json".

I tried sending it with content-type "multipart/form-data" or "application/octet-stream", but it also fails...

```
// this "url" gives me the "data:data:image/png;base64, " code
var sourceImageUrl = document.getElementById("myImage").src;

    // Perform the REST API call.
    $.ajax({
        url: uriBase + "?" + $.param(params),

        // Request headers.
        beforeSend: function(jqXHR){
            jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","multipart/form-data");
            jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);
        },

        type: "POST",

        // Request body.
        data: [sourceImageUrl]
    })

    .done(function(data) {
        // Show formatted JSON on webpage.
        $("#responseTextArea").val(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    })

    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // Display error message.
        var errorString = (errorThrown === "") ?
            "Error. " : errorThrown + " (" + jqXHR.status + "): ";
        errorString += (jqXHR.responseText === "") ? "" :
            (jQuery.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText).message) ?
                jQuery.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText).message :
                jQuery.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText).error.message;
        alert(errorString);
    });
```

I am bit confused about how I should be sending the image or if I should do some transformations.

Which content-type should I be using to do a proper request?
Should I change the encoding of the image source? How?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it working by adding a makeBlob function that returns a blob out of a base64 code. I also set the content-type to  "application/octet-stream".

Final code looks like this:

```
    function makeblob(b64Data, contentType, sliceSize) {
     contentType = contentType || '';
     sliceSize = sliceSize || 512;

     var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
     var byteArrays = [];

     for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
         var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

         var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
         for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
             byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
         }

         var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

         byteArrays.push(byteArray);
     }

     var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, { type: contentType });
     return blob;
 }


function recognizeText() {
    imageToSend = image.src;

    binDataImage = imageToSend.replace("data:image/png;base64,","");

        // Perform the REST API call.
        $.ajax({
            url: uriBase + "?" + $.param(params),

            // Request headers.
            beforeSend: function(jqXHR){
                jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/octet-stream");
                jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);
            },

            type: "POST",

            // Request body.
            data: makeblob(binDataImage, 'image/jpeg'),
            cache: false,
            processData: false
        })

        .done(function(data) {
            // Show formatted JSON on webpage.
            $("#responseTextArea").val(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
        })

        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // Display error message.
            var errorString = (errorThrown === "") ?
                "Error. " : errorThrown + " (" + jqXHR.status + "): ";
            errorString += (jqXHR.responseText === "") ? "" :
                (jQuery.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText).message) ?
                    jQuery.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText).message :
                    jQuery.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText).error.message;
            alert(errorString);
        });
  };
```